# Steal cookie from webview

Tags: ios, cookies, web, webview

In my application I'm using cookies to implement "Remember me" feature. User is login via webview and if login will succeed webpage will set cookie. Then this cookie is using to login user automatically during next app launches. I'm wondering how secure is this cookie on device. Is there any way to steal users cookie without Jailbreaking device? If yes how can I make it secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is too broad for responding particularly - you should think about narrowing down following points:

- Are you using `WKWebView` or `UIWebView`? They use completely different approaches for cookies management.
- What attack vectors do you expect and what level of security has sense in terms of your product?

In general, the safety level and attack vectors are approximately the same as of general browser. You can look into [OWASP TOP-10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) to ensure your web application is secure against main attack vectors.

From device point of view cookies are possible to steal from the unlocked device from a file system (using apps like iExplorer) - you can use [iOS Data Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW21) feature.

**EDIT**

To view cookies via iExplorer:

1. Download [it](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/);
2. Connect iPhone and unlock it
3. Launch iExplorer, select your device -> Apps -> Your app
4. You'll see the app's container file system hierarchy
5. Navigate Library->Cookies
6. Select .binarycookies file and export it to your Mac file system (right click -> Export in iExplorer)
7. Use .binarycookies [reader](http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/10/27/cookies-binarycookies-reader/)

Comment: can you please explain me how I can get cookie from device with iExplorer? I think thats what I need to take care.